# Get whole domain content with wget or other commands in linux?

Tags: linux, wget

I would like to copy a client project but I only have FTP-access. Normally I'd do it with SSH-access, but in this case it's not possible. The problem is the size of the project (nearly 3GB)

Is there a solution to copy the project to my server only with FTP-access?

Comment: Are you asking if there are FTP client applications that are able to copy?

Comment: No. I could download the whole project but the upload would be complicated because of the size. I thought there could be a way to do it with wget

Comment: Why is the size complicating things ? What's the actual problem ? Do you just want to run `wget -r ftp://server/folder/` , or issue a `recursive mget *` command in an ftp client ?

Comment: Do you want to copy a project from the remote computer to the same remote computer using your ftp client?

Comment: Now I tried wget -r ftp://user:pass@domain but the problem is that the username contains an @ and so I get an error

Comment: There are many ways to specify the user name and password mentioned in the wget documentation. Try another method.

Answer (score 0):

The size isn't the problem here. Because of the encryption a SSH upload produces much more overhead than a FTP upload, therefore the answer is: Of course you can use FTP for file uploads, even if they large uploads. FTP was meant for this.

The more important concern is security. If you are normally using SSH for file uploads you'll for sure having security in mind (because FTP would been faster than SSH). If your provider does support SFTP you could use it as an alternative.